# Setting User language for Localization/Globalization

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to select the language based on the user choice and set it for the entire session.
Can anybody suggest where do i need to do these settings and how can i do this?

Comment: what sort of session? is this about asp.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution by setting the current thread in global.asax

```
protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Session["userCultureInfo"] != null)
                {
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(Session["userCultureInfo"].ToString());

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

See [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx).
 A tutorial can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508(v=VS.85).aspx) . Briefly: change  [`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture.aspx) and  [`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentuiculture.aspx)

Comment: its okay but i need to set this for the entire application.
I tried to override the InitializeCulture() method of the page. But that again sets the culture for the page only. And when i navigates to anther page these settings dont work

Comment: One way to set the culture for the entire application is to set this in globalization tag of the web.config. But I need to do it programatically. I mean this will be on the based on the user's choice. So do i need to make changes in the web.config dynamically?

Comment: Or is there any possibility with global.asax file?

Comment: In the tutorial link I gave there is an example "The following code example shows an ASP.NET Web page that lets users select their preferred language from a drop-down list. ". Doesn't that help?